# Python UDP Broadcast Transport Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

I sent a UDP broadcast using Python 3.7.3.

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
sock.bind(('', 12345))
sock.settimeout(1)

sock.sendto('ABCD'.encode(), ('255.255.255.255', 5048))

while 1:
    try:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    except socket.timeout:
        print('socket timeout')
        sock.sendto('ABCD'.encode(), ('255.255.255.255', 5048))
```

I could not confirm the broadcast on Wire Shark.

Answer (score 0):

[solved]
I changed the 'Npcap Loopback Adapter' to 'Disabled' in the Ethernet adapter option, and I was able to see the UDP packets from the wire shark.
But I do not know why this is happening.
I would like advice.